# toubleshooting sccm with agent push

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sccm-2012

My problem: I have SCCM 2012 and when I try to push agent, I receive  ab error saying: unable to connect to wmi on remote machine..

I checked ports, turned off firewall on both client and server, check dns for duplication , but still cannot push client to windows user..

for some users I could to push agent to client.

Does anyone has idea how to install SCCM2012 client manually??

Answer (score 0):

"CCMSetup.exe and its supporting files are located on the System Center 2012 Configuration Manager site server in the Client folder of the System Center 2012 Configuration Manager installation folder. This folder is shared to the network as \SMS_\Client."

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699356.aspx:

"CCMSetup.exe /mp:%ManagementPoint% SMSMP=%ManagementPoint% SMSSITECODE=%SiteCode% FSP=%FallbackStatusPointIfApplicable%"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394603(VS.85).aspx - Check this out as well for the error.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall was blocking SCCM to push agent to the clients. When I look to logs I found the up error.